# Keyboard shortcut for creating new file on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Can someone please tell me how to create a new keyboard shortcut for creating a new text file?

I have installed `Autohotkey` but I don't know how to specify script. I want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> as keyboard shortcut for new file creation.

Please tell me script for this shortcut as their tutorial seems to be of not much help.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this.

Type this into *Notepad* and **save as** **Notepad.bat**.

```
START "" notepad.exe
```

[image]

Next save Notepad.bat in your documents like below or another Directory.

I saved mine here **C:\Users\MBurris\Documents\Notepad**

[image]

**Next Right click and make a shortcu**t. Drag this shortcut to your desktop.
**Right click the shortcut** and rename it to **Notepad**.
[image]

Now add your hotkey to the shortcut. <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

[image]

**Optional.**

Finally to make this look clean.

You have the option to **hide the shortcut**.

Open Cmd and type `attrib Notepad.lnk +s +h`

[image]

Thats it now just use <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and Notepad will open up.

[image]

Note: to unhide this use

```
attrib Notepad.lnk -s -h
```

Comment: Thanks, it is not exactly what I wanted but its close.

Comment: Well what do you want then?  You got two good answers, neither of which you built upon or clarified.  What do you mean by "creating a new text file"?... do you want it saved on disk somewhere and opened in an editor?  Do you want an empty text file sitting somewhere on your hard drive?

Answer (score 3):

Using AutoHotkey:

```
!^n::
if WinActive("ahk_class Progman") or WinActive("ahk_class WorkerW") ; desktop
{
    FileAppend,, %A_Desktop%\New Textfile.txt
    Run, %A_Desktop%\New Textfile.txt
}
else
if WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") ; explorer
{
    for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
    try Fullpath := window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
    FileAppend,, %Fullpath%\New Textfile.txt
    Run, %Fullpath%\New Textfile.txt
}
return
```

Comment: Thanks, it is not exactly what I wanted but its close.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows Explorer keyboard shortcut** (without AutoHotkey)

In Windows Explorer, you can hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd> to create a new text file in the current folder.

**Explanation**

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>: Opens the *File* menu of Windows Explorer
- <kbd>W</kbd>: Opens the *New* menu
- <kbd>T</kbd>: Selects the *Text Document* entry

[image: Menu File - New - Text Document]

**AutoHotkey**

You could simulate those keystrokes with an AutoHotkey script mapped to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> keyboard shortcut you want:

```
!^n::
Send, !f
Send, w
Send, t
return
```